# Python: all print output not present when written to a file

Tags: python

I am new to python and I need a help with a code that I am working with.

I am fetching output from an api using a list of inputs from a csv file.
I can see the output when I print the result which is good.

I see the output of the first input value only where the rest are not being printed, in the output.txt file.

For example, I input the numbers 1 to 10 and I see the output for all in the print statement output. But when I write it to a file, I see the output of the number 1 only where the rest are not written inside the file.

FYI, the api output does not have any "data" field but just the output enclosed in {}

Please help me with it and lemme know if you have any further questions on the topic.

Expecting all output to be in the text file rather than just one from a list of 10s or 100s.

Comment: hey mate, welcome to stackoverflow! please attach your code so we'll be able to figure out the problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing to the file with the append mode on or write, because it should be append.

Comment: I have written the code with write mode because I do not want to add existing details again and again as per my understanding on append keyword.

Comment: I was implying that if you have a list of values you can loop over them and append them to the file

Answer (score -1):

As there is no reference code you have provided so it's difficult to check which part of your code cause issue. You can use  my code as :

```
import csv
import requests

# This will read the input values from csv file
with open('your_input_file_name.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    input_values = [row[0] for row in reader]

# This will fetch the output from API for each input value and write to your_output_file_name.txt file
with open('your_output_file_name.txt', 'w') as f:
    for value in input_values:
        response = requests.get('YOUR_API_URL', params={'input': value})
        output = response.json()

        f.write(str(output) + '\n')
```

Hope this help !!